# Handle OAuth2 authentication failure using Apigee proxy

Tags: apigee

I've written my own login app to protect my api following the [oauth-login-app](https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/tree/master/sample-proxies/oauth-login-app) example.

I've implemented the web server flow and everything works great.

My question is: how should I handle an authentication failure at step 3? How do I tell he client app that the authentication failed? The user could either press the cancel button, or refuse permission or just enter the wrong details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initiate OAuth 2.0 (dance) with

```
/authorize
```

1. the user-agent land on `/login` page (created/hosted by you),
   post redirect.
2. enduser(user-agent) submits the username/password
   to the page hosted by you. Here you collect the credentials and
   submit to Apigee, and if authentication fails, send a HTTP 401
   response. Now your application should be in position to re-render
   the login page and with a flash "invalid credential".
3. Now coming to if user is authenticated but rejects the authorization request in
   consent page, you should redirect to the "`redirect_uri`" provided
   by client, with error code.

Answer (score 1):

```
How do I tell he client app that the authentication failed?
```

The login app will redirect the control back to the application redirect URI - with added error code/description in the URL as hash parameters. In case of success the URL is appended with code or token.

You can do this redirect from your login app directly but I would suggest to make the redirect call first to an Apigee Proxy and let Apigee Proxy send the redirect back to app.  Both in case of success and failure. In this way you will have the benefit of using Apigee analytics that helps your understand how many OAuths failed for what reason etc.

EDIT:
You can use the same GenerateAuthorizationCode proxy you have built for the success flow. When login fails or succeeds, in either case you need to pass that information to this proxy. Generally the login app and this proxy should share this information using a common session store. You can not pass this information just using a redirect parameter because that can be changed by the client user agent.  When you redirect to the GenerateAuthorizationCode redirect proxy, do so by appending a random session ID in the URL. That id can be used by the GenerateAuthorizationCode proxy to look up the login status from the session store. Then you can either send back a redirect with error or a proper oauth code based on if the login was successful.  An easy implementation of the session store can be done using a distributed caching resource in the apigee gateway. Login app can put/get the session using an internal API. While the proxy can use policies to retrieve the session information.

Comment: I've got a GenerateAuthorizationCode proxy setup and when successful my login app redirects to `/oauth/authorizationcode?client_id=%s&response_type=code&app_enduser=%s`

When login fails should I use the same proxy? How do I pass the error code back? Or should I create a completely different proxy?